# how to change border color on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change colors in a random order when I click with that colors "red", "hotpink", "greenyellow", "tomato", "lightcoral", "lightblue":

```
function changeColor() {
     document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor=red", "hotpink", "greenyellow ", "tomato", "lightcoral", "lightblue"
```

Comment: "*when I click with that colors "red", "hotpink"*" - where are those 'colors' listed? What element(s) should be changed, what is the user clicking on? Where's your (relevant) HTML? Please: take the [tour], and read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: 'random order' doesn't make sense. Is it a random color, or a cycle of colors? Is it a cycle of colors that starts at a random color? Is it a cycle that gets pre-generated randomly?

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers it was very helpful
and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers here seem to be generating a random *index* so the generated color is always random.

To change the color in a random *order*, shuffle the array of colors using the [Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and use a variable to keep track of the index.

```js
var colors = shuffle(["red", "hotpink", "greenyellow ", "tomato", "lightcoral", "lightblue"]);
var i = 0;
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor = colors[i];
  if (colors.length - 1 == i) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}

function shuffle(r){for(var f,n=r.length;0!==n;)f=Math.floor(Math.random()*n),n--,[r[n],r[f]]=[r[f],r[n]];return r}
```

```css
#box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 10px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">

</div>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 mostly because the rest of the answers doesn't check if they randomized the same color again. So you can get "red", "red", "red" several times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can JavaScript `Math.random()` function.

```js
function changeColor(){
  var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];

  document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor =  colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

```css
#box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#box:hover{
cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="changeColor();">

<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const div = document.getElementById("a");
const colorArr = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "yellow"];


function changeColor() {
  
  // grab a color from the array ;

  // step one grab a random index from the array or colorArr 
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colorArr.length + 1));

  // console.log(index);
  div.style.borderColor = colorArr[index]
}

function changeColor2() {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  div.style.borderColor = "#" + randomColor
  
  // https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp
}
```

```css
#a{
  border: 25px solid red;
  width: 235px;
  height: 235px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: "black"
}
```

```html
<div id="a"> </div>
<button onclick = "changeColor()"> Click me </button>
<button onclick = "changeColor2()"> More Random Colors </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let colors = ["red", "hotpink", "greenyellow ", "tomato", "lightcoral", "lightblue"];
function changeColor() {
       document.getElementById("box").style.borderColor=colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend that put color in array and  generate a random number between 0-4 and fetch that array element .